# Creating random mp3 file list for input to Media Player

Tags: powershell, audio, random, filepath

I'm somewhat of a novice in Powershell programming, but I'm trying to create a random list of 50 mp3 files to use as input to play in Media Player.  I've got the random file list part almost down, but am struggling to get to the next level.  Here is what I've got:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem E:\'My Music'\Pop_Rock\*\ -Recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | Select-Object FullName
$Samplefiles = $Files | Get-Random -Count 50
foreach ($Song in $Samplefiles)
{
    echo $Song
    echo "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $Song"
    C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $Song
    #Start-Sleep 10
}
```

This gets 50 random files from my Music directory as I want (snippet of 5 filenames retrieved)

```
echo $Song
E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\B\Brian Setzer\Brian Setzer - The Dirty Boogie\09 - Since I Don't Have You.mp3
E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\K\Korn\Korn - Untouchables\10 - Leave This Place.mp3
E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\C\The Cars\The Cars - Heartbeat City\02 - Looking For Love.mp3
E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\E\Elvis Presley\Elvis Presley - The Essential 60's Masters II - Command Performances\124 - Bossa …
E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\S\Starship\Starship - Love Among the Cannibals\02 - It's Not Enough.mp3
```

My problem is, when I run this as a powershell script, the $Song variable does not resolve correctly.

```
echo $Song
E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\D\David Bowie\David Bowie - Heathen\08 - Gemini Spacecraft.mp3
```

echo of the command

```
C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe @{FullName=E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\D\David Bowie\David Bowie - Heathen\08 - Gemini Spacecraft.mp3}

E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\V\Van Halen\Van Halen - Van Halen II\10 - Beautiful Girls.mp3

C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe @{FullName=E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\V\Van Halen\Van Halen - Van Halen II\10 - Beautiful Girls.mp3}

E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\C\Christina Aguilera\Christina Aguilera - Stripped\06 - Infatuation.mp3

C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe @{FullName=E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\C\Christina Aguilera\Christina Aguilera - Stripped\06 - Infatuation.mp3}

E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\W\The Who\The Who - Quadrophenia\103 - Quadrophenia.mp3

C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe @{FullName=E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\W\The Who\The Who - Quadrophenia\103 - Quadrophenia.mp3}

E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\T\Ted Nugent\Ted Nugent - Free For All\06 - Together.mp3

C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe @{FullName=E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\T\Ted Nugent\Ted Nugent - Free For All\06 - Together.mp3}
```

I've tested the command C:'Program Files (x86)''Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe in Powershell with a single file (like this) E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\T'Ted Nugent''Ted Nugent - Free For All\06 - Together'.mp3, and it works as I want, just not sure how to solve this variable/file path problem.

Any help appreciated.

Best regards,

Moosehead

Comment: Right, because `$song` is an object. You have to expand the property you want, so in your case, it would be: `echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe $($Song.FullName)"` . The subexpression operator `$(..)` allows references to properties of variable objects within a string to be interpolated properly; basically expands it for you.

Comment: This can also be shorted to `(Get-ChildItem "E:\My Music\Pop_Rock\" -Filter "*.mp3" -File -Recurse).FullName`. Then there wouldn't be a need to use `$()`, or use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` instead, although the first method is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Like @abraham stated - you need to expand the "FullName" property.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem E:\'My Music'\Pop_Rock\*\ -Recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | Select-Object FullName
$Samplefiles = $Files | Get-Random -Count 50
foreach ($Song in $Samplefiles)
{
    Write-Verbose -Message $Song
    Write-Verbose -Message ("C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe {0}" -f $Song.FullName)
    #C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $Song.FullName
    #Start-Sleep 10
}
```

It seems we're all overthinking this. If you just want to make a playlist you can dump them to an .m3u and open that.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem C:\Powershell\Scripts -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 
$Files | Get-Random -Count 50 |  Out-File -Encoding UTF8  tempplaylist.m3u


Test-Path .\tempplaylist.m3u
Write-Verbose -Message "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe tempplaylist.m3u" 
#C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe tempplaylist.m3u
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the guidance.  The only thing left to make this work perfectly is to get the process to wait until the first song is over before the next one starts (and cuts off the end of the first).  I thought the Start-Sleep would do that, but that doesn't seem to be working unless I make the sleep really long as below (current code inserted here)

Comment: $Files = Get-ChildItem E:\'My Music'\Pop_Rock\*\ -Recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | Select-Object FullName

$Samplefiles = $Files | Get-Random -Count 5

foreach ($Song in $Samplefiles)
{
    echo $($Song.FullName)
    echo "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $($Song.FullName)"
    
C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $($Song.FullName)
    Start-Sleep 360
}

Comment: @Moosehead see my edit

Comment: That's a great thought, but playlists are formatted files as opposed to a list of files.  I might try creating that formatted file as part of my ps script...  This is all new and great stuff to me, so learning as I go

Comment: @Moosehead you're right. I think you could cook up something that measure the length of the file and then waits for that duration but it'd be complex. Let me know if you want to go down that route before i put more effort into it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.  This one works pretty well.

Comment: $Files = Get-ChildItem E:\'My Music'\Pop_Rock\*\ -Recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | Select-Object FullName
$Samplefiles = $Files | Get-Random -Count 25
foreach ($Song in $Samplefiles)
{
    echo $($Song.FullName)
    echo "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $($Song.FullName)"
    C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Windows Media Player'\wmplayer.exe $($Song.FullName)
    echo "Start-Sleep 270"
    Start-Sleep 270
    $wmid = Get-Process wmplayer
    echo $($wmid.Id)
    echo "Stop-Process -Id $($wmid.Id)
    Stop-Process -Id $($wmid.Id)
}

Comment: I've played with using Start-Process and Wait-Process, but those haven't worked for me yet.  I'll continue to try those, and if I get those working, will post the update